# NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished vs. performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsoperationqueue

I have background **NSInvocationOperation** creating and saving **NSArray** to the **NSManagedObject** subclass.

I know that save should happen on main thread, so I use **performSelectorOnMainThread** for save in the operation.

When user pushes home button on iPhone 3G, app is going to quit. In **applicationDidEnterBackground** I do **[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]**, so that NSInvocationOperation has time to finish.

The problem is, that it waits only for "background part" of the operation - **app is shutted down before performSelectorOnMainThread part of the operation is called**. This means my NSManagedObject is not saved.

I tried to save object in operation's thread - app is shutted gracefully and changes are saved. But I think this is not good as NSManagedObject is not thread safe. Or is it OK to do this?

It seems like catch 22. I must be missing something - is there any elegant way how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just do the save operation in the background using a separate context that notifies the main context. This means creating, fetching, and saving managed objects should be done on this separate context and this is documented in the [Core Data - Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). You should also start a [background task](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to ensure you have enough time to finish saving the data.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid I should do all this, but it was not that bad :) I had also to change merge policy on secondary context to NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy as some other properties of the same object are in the meantime changed and saved in main context.

Comment: Ah thats good, it seems like a lot at first but really isn't that bad. I have a sync operation where I set the merge policy to overwrite.